# Deleting contents of last cell of html table row

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html table that includes rows:

```
<tr id="firstInRow"><td></td><td><input name="longP1" id="longP1" type="text" style="width: 70px"></td><td><input name="latP1" id="latP1" type="text" style="width: 70px"></td><td>(upper left)</td></tr>
<tr id="secInRow"><td></td><td><input name="longP2" id="longP2" type="text" style="width: 70px"></td><td><input name="latP2" id="latP2" type="text" style="width: 70px"></td><td>(lower right)</td></tr>
```

which creates a table like this:
[latLongTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg6A9.png)

I have already created an add row function that works, and I am trying to delete the contents of the last cells in that function. I want to remove the text "(upper left)" and "(lower right)". I tried a couple of ways, including:

```
var rowIn1 = document.getElementById("firstInRow");
rowIn1.deleteCell(-1);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: why not just hide the cell with css? - `tr td:last-child {display:none;}`

Comment: @Pete I am trying to do this inside of a javascript function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .remove() function of jQuery.
For example:

```
$("#firstInRow").find("td:last-child").remove();
```

This will find the last column (td) of the row with id *firstInRow* and remove it from DOM. You can remove the other cell using the same method.

If you want to remove the content only then use:

```
$("#firstInRow").find("td:last-child").text('');
```

This will not remove the last column from DOM, instead it will clear the content from last column.

```js
$("#clear").on("click", function() {
$("#firstInRow").find("td:last").text("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr id="firstInRow">
<td>First</td>
<td>Last</td>
<td>Content to clear</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="clear">Clear last column</button>
</body>
```